# Get data from SIDRA (Brazil) with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to automate my worksheet with data from the SIDRA website, a Brazilian database.

Edit: I am trying to download the Industrial Production data. The link provided takes to the series table, than I have to select in "Variável" the first box (Índice de base fixa sem ajuste sazonal (Base: média de 2012 = 100) (Número-índice)), in "Seções e atividades industriais (CNAE 2.0)" also first box, and in "Mês" (month in Portuguese) all the boxes (the whole time series).

I have this code:

```
Private Sub FazDownload(nomed As String, nomea As String)
Dim FileNum As Long
Dim FileData() As Byte
Dim MyFile As String
Dim WHTTP As Object

On Error Resume Next
    Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")
    End If
On Error GoTo 0

MyFile = "http://www.sidra.ibge.gov.br/download/" & nomed & ".tsv"


WHTTP.Open "GET", MyFile, False
WHTTP.Send
FileData = WHTTP.ResponseBody
Set WHTTP = Nothing

FileNum = FreeFile
Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nomea & ".tsv" For Binary Access Write As #FileNum
    Put #FileNum, 1, FileData
Close #FileNum

End Sub

Private Sub pim_setoresindustria()

Dim ie As Object
Dim optCollection

Dim nomeper As String
nomeper = "industria" & DateDiff("s", #1/1/1970#, Now())

'Starts Internet Explorer
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

   'Opens IE in the SIDRA webpage
    ie.Navigate "http://www.sidra.ibge.gov.br/bda/tabela/listabl.asp?z=t&o=1&i=P&c=3653"
    ie.Visible = True

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Selects the characteristics of the table -- HERE IT STOPS WORKING
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        ie.Document.all("opv").Value = 1
        ie.Document.all("pov").Value = 3
        ie.Document.all("orv").Value = 3

        'Selects specific data series on the menu 
        Set optCollection = ie.Document.all("sev").Options
            For Each opt In optCollection
                opt.Selected = (opt.Value = 3135 Or opt.Value = 3134)
                'Or opt.Value = 3136 Or opt.Value = 3137 Or opt.Value = 3138)
            Next


        ie.Document.all("opc544").Value = 2
        ie.Document.all("poc544").Value = 3
        ie.Document.all("orc544").Value = 2

        ie.Document.all("opp").Value = 2
        ie.Document.all("pop").Value = 2

        ie.Document.all("compressao").Click
        ie.Document.all("compressao").Click

        ie.Document.all("formato").Value = 4
        ie.Document.all("modalidade").Value = 1
        ie.Document.all("arquivo").Value = nomeper

        ie.Document.all("gera").Click

    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Waits 1 minute to start the download
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
    FazDownload nomeper, "pim"

ie.Quit

End Sub
```

The code is supposed to open the data table from the SIDRA website, and copy it to the worksheet. It used to work (my company has been updating this data for a while), but recently it stoped working. The person that wrote it does not work with us anymore, and I can't understand the part where it selects the options from the SIDRA table. (marked with -- HERE IT STOPS WORKING)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like they have redesigned the page and there are no longer any elements named "opv", "pov" or "orv"

Comment: Can you describe what you are after from the page?

Comment: @TimWilliams if there were elements named "opv", "pov" or "orv", how would they me shown? Should I be looking at the explicit words at the page, or on it´s code? I could maybe try to find the new names of those elements.

Comment: @QHarr I am trying to download the Industrial Production data. The link provided takes to the series table, than I have to select "Variável" as the first box (Índice de base fixa sem ajuste sazonal (Base: média de 2012 = 100) (Número-índice)), "Seções e atividades industriais (CNAE 2.0)" also first box, and "Mês" (month in Portuguese) as all.

Answer (score 0):

I will improve on this by introducing API calls to get the handle for the save dialogue. That will be more robust but here is a functioning first version.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetDownload()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://sidra.ibge.gov.br/Tabela/3653"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Dim variávelOpções  As Object, variávelRótulos  As Object, opção As Long
        Set variávelOpções = .document.querySelectorAll("#panel-V-collapse .sidra-toggle")
        Set variávelRótulos = .document.querySelectorAll("#panel-V-collapse [data-indice]")

        For opção = 0 To variávelOpções.Length - 1
            If opção = 0 Then
                If Not variávelOpções.item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then
                    variávelOpções.item(opção).Click
                End If
            Else
                If variávelOpções.item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then
                    variávelOpções.item(opção).Click
                End If
            End If
        Next

        Dim seçõesOuAtividades As Object, seçõesOuAtividadesRótulos As Object
        Set seçõesOuAtividades = .document.querySelectorAll("#panel-C544-collapse .sidra-toggle")
        Set seçõesOuAtividadesRótulos = .document.querySelectorAll("#panel-C544-collapse [data-indice]")

        If opção = 0 Then
            If Not seçõesOuAtividades.item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then
                seçõesOuAtividades.item(opção).Click
            End If
        Else
            If seçõesOuAtividades.item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then
                seçõesOuAtividades.item(opção).Click
            End If
        End If

        .document.querySelector("#panel-P-collapse [data-cmd=marcarTudo]").Click

        .document.querySelector("#botao-downloads").Click

        .document.querySelector("#opcao-downloads").Click

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

        Application.SendKeys "%{S}"

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

        Application.SendKeys "%{O}"

        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, @QHarr! I´ll try to work on your improvements.
The code still stops in 
 For opção = 0 To variávelOpções.Length - 1
            If opção = 0 Then
                If Not variávelOpções.item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then

Comment: What does it say when it stops? Is there an error message? What is it please?

Comment: it says "Run-time error '424'. Object required"
The error takes to: "If Not seçõesOuAtividades.Item(opção).getAttribute("aria-selected") Then"

Comment: What is the value of debug.print variávelOpções.Length ?

Comment: I have run it lots of time here without a problem.